# Flutter doctor command but nothing happen

Tags: flutter

I use a MacBook Pro and install flutter, but when I type `flutter doctor`, it doesn't respond (about 10 minutes passed).

[flutter doctor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3F5X.png)

this [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18869) same to me, but I don't install Mamp software.

Answer (score 4):

If on Windows and flutter doctor is not responding , it means it needs administrative privileges.
Just go to search bar , find Command prompt and run it as administrator. That should do.

Answer (score 1):

Without sounding silly, are you connected online? This happens to me when I'm disconnected from the Internet.

Also, what happens when you do this?

```
> flutter upgrade
```

Does it still lock up then, or does it actually check the version before eventually continuing and running flutter doctor?

Comment: I do what i can do, but  useless！
”reinstall system“  it  work!

Comment: That did not work for me.  Same issue.  Dart SDK blows up as soon as I run any Flutter commands

Comment: @BobSmall, what version are you on (`flutter --version`)? Are you able to reinstall flutter, or download the latest version (go to directory above where flutter is installed and executing `git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git`)?

Comment: @Eddie Eddie Eddie. Flutter 1.22.4 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 1aafb3a8b9 (13 days ago) • 2020-11-13 09:59:28 -0800
Engine • revision 2c956a31c0
Tools • Dart 2.10.4

Answer (score 1):

try to run command : `flutter`
maybe you get some error, and fix it.
i also get error:

```
The term 'Unblock-File' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, sc
ript file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path wa
s included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:13
+ Unblock-File <<<<  -Path 'C:\src\flutter/bin/internal/update_dart_sdk.ps1'; &
 'C:\src\flutter/bin/internal/update_dart_sdk.ps1'
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Unblock-File:String) [], Comman
   dNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Flutter requires PowerShell 5.0 or newer.
See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows for more.
Building flutter tool...
Running pub upgrade...
The current Dart SDK version is 2.1.0-dev.9.4.flutter-f9ebf21297.

Because flutter_tools requires SDK version >=2.2.2 <3.0.0, version solving
  failed.
```

and i fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If on windows try open task manager and end/terminate all dart.exe processes, might be flutter doctor waiting on another dart.exe process to finish that for whatever reason is not finishing